# Save data from histogram in text file

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Currently I am plotting a histogram using matplotlib.pyplot to plot my data in a histogram.
But now I want to save this data in a textfile. Here I want the first column to be the x value and the second to be the y value. How can I do this?

I plot my histogram in the following order:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

some_list = [0.42146137, 0.42146137, etc...]


plt.hist(some_list, bins = 900, histtype="step", cumulative=-1)
plt.yscale("log")
```

Comment: `cumulative=-1` is the same as `cumulative=True`, because any number other than 0 is considered to be "True". Is this what  you really wanted?

Comment: Actually if cumulative evaluates to less than 0 (e.g., -1), the direction of accumulation is reversed.

Comment: Wow, wtf. I just checked the docs and you are right. I assumed that because the default value was boolean, all it did was turn that feature on/off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign plt.hist() to a value, then the first elemnt is the ys, the second is the xs. `a = plt.hist(); ys = a[0]; xs = a[1]`. Then you can write with any method, like `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()`, depending on what structure you want. Keep in mind, the `xs` are actually boundaries, starting with the lower bound of the first, ending with the upper bound of the last, so the length of `xs` is one greater than the length of `ys`.

So for example, if you want just the upper bounds, maybe something like this: `pd.DataFrame({'x_upper':a[1][1:], 'y': a[0]}).to_csv(filename)`

Comment: Thank you! Never worked with pandas data frame before so one last question... what if I wanted the entire graph and not only the upper bound. So for example my first point is at 0.4 and my last at 1.0 and I wanted each y-value with an interval of 0.01 (so 0.41, 0,42 ... 1).

Comment: hmm can't quickly think of a super easy way off the top of my head... could do either a for loop over that sequence while checking against the bounds list. Or maybe make that sequence as a one-column dataframe and do some fancy join onto your other table. Other folks might have cleaner ideas.

Comment: And just to verify this is what you really want... Because you could also force the bins of the hist to be every 0.01, which would give you the actual frequencies of the smaller bins. What you are asking for I believe would give you basically coordinates of a line graph in the shape of a hist, but not the correct values for those smaller 0.01 bins.

Comment: Also, with 900 bins, your x vals would actually be closer than every 0.01... so I guess I'm not 100% sure what you are asking.

Comment: Ah yes adjusting the bins is good enough in my case indeed :). Thanks!

Comment: awesome, no problem!